# Python making tuple of an array with a step 2

Tags: python, loops

```
els = [1, 2, 3, 4, ]
print([(v, els[idx + 1]) for idx, v in enumerate(els[::2])])
```

Why does Python output `[(1, 2), (3, 3)]` instead of `[(1, 2), (3,` **4**`)]`?

PS: I know I could do this: `[(els[i], els[i + 1]) for i in range(0,len(els),2)]` I'm not asking for a solution, I'm asking *why is this*?

Comment: You have a good explanation in the answer below, but FWIW, an easier pattern for this is `list(zip(els[::2], els[1::2]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is this?

Take closer look at `enumerate(els[::2])`, consider following simple code

```
els = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for elem in enumerate(els[::2]):
    print(elem)
```

gives output

```
(0, 1)
(1, 3)
(2, 5)
(3, 7)
(4, 9)
```

Observe that numbering was applied *after* slicing but you are using index to access element of list *before* slicing and they are not in unison.